# How to return index of an array in a user defined function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a user-defined function (not mine, in a plug-in) which returns an array of values in column A. I also have the following (array) formula in column B, which returns all the cells in column A which contain some specified string:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$256,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,$A$1:$A$256)),ROW($A$1:$A$256)),ROW(2:2)))
```

This uses the ROW() function to get the row(s) of the matching elements. This all works fine.

However, I would like to clean up my sheet a little, and do something like the following:

```
=INDEX(UDF(),SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,UDF())),ROW(UDF())),ROW(2:2)))
```

Youll notice I have replaced the array '$A$1:$A$256' with the returned array from my UDF. This seems to break at the ROW(UDF()) part. Is there a similar function, which return the index of the array, or 'row'?

NOTE: I would rather not do this in VBA, and I cannot edit the UDF (it is not mine).

EDIT:

OK I have a bit more information. If I do as suggested in the comments, and evaluate the formula, all the evaluation returns is the first element of the array. This brought up a related, second question. How does one do this with a UDF? If you are familiar with Bloomberg, you will know that when you call some BDH or BDP formula (NOT calling it as an array formula), it fills a range with values. How does this happen?! I feel like if i know the answer to this question, it will help me understand what is happening in this particular UDF.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is breaking the formula without seeing the UDF in question. Perhaps it is returning a string representing the cell range and not the actual range. Can you get `=SUN(UDF())` or =`COUNTA(UDF())` to work? What does the UDF return? Try `=INDEX(INDIRECT(UDF()), ...` .

Comment: You can also try `=UDF()` and then using "Evaluate Formula" it will output the result of the UDF before parsing that and presenting the final value. You can then see if the result of UDF is a range (Given by it's address ie `=A1:A256`) or a specific value. Regards,

Comment: Similar to @Jeeped, does the UDF return an `Array` or a `Range`?  I don't think the `Array` version is going to work with `ROW` based on a simple test here.

Comment: I do not know how to tell the difference. The UDF is buried in a password protected plug in so I cannot see it. How do I tell the difference? It returns a variable-sized single column of cells. What I mean is you put the formula in cell A1, and it returns values for cells A1 to Ax where x is a varying number of return values. Does that make sense? Does that help?